# Confused about a quality of Existential Generalization and Instantiation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Let me preface the question with a "proof"

$1. \exists yP(y)  \quad Premise \\ 2. P(B) \quad \quad 1,E.I.  \\ 3. \exists xP(x)  \quad 2,E.G.  $

However, I am not sure if it is to "safe" to say that I derived $\exists xP(x) $ because I am confused about whether it is correct to say that B exits in X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your system of natural deduction. In LPL's system, the proof would go:

$\begin{array}{ccccc}
1. & \exists yP(y) & Premise\\
2. &  & \boxed{b} & Subproof\\
3. &  & P(b) & 1,\exists-Elim\\
4. & \exists xP(x) & 2-3,\exists-Intro
\end{array}$